# How to remove spaces from specific column using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I just want to modify the second column "Name" and remove all the spaces from between the name and leave the rest of the txt file untouched and further, print it.

Here is my input  (Tab separated fields):

```
Roll NO Name         RandomColumn1    RandomColumn2 
1       Jason James  my value        my val 3
```

My Desired output:

```
Roll NO Name        RandomColumn1  RandomColumn2 
1       JasonJames  my value        my val 3
```

Command that I had been using but been unsuccessful with:

```
 awk '{$3=$4;  print }' | sed "s/^ *//"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }{ gsub(" ", "", $2) }1' infile
```

FS is the input Field Separator; OFS is the Output Field Separator; both sets to a Tab `\t` character, then we remove (replaces with empty string) all the space characters within second field and print the final update with [the `1`](/q/63891/72456) used.

Answer (score 0):

Employing **GNU sed** in its extended regex mode `-E` we can do it like as shown. First fence off the second field with markers (`\n`) known to be absent from the pattern space. Then in a loop pick off any space in between these markers and post loop revert the market s to field separators.

```
sed -Ee '
  s/\t/\n/;s//\n/;ta
  :a
    s/(\n.*) (.*\n)/\1\2/
  ta
  y/\n/\t/
' file
```

---

We can use **python3** and nested list comprehension to get the desired output:

```
python3 -c 'import sys
ifs,ors,ifile = "\t", "\n",sys.argv[1]
spc,ofs = " ",ifs
with open(ifile) as f:
  print(*[ofs.join([f1,f2.replace(spc,""),f3_])    
for l in f for f1,f2,f3_ in [l.rstrip().split(ifs,2)]],sep=ors)
' file
```

---

```
perl -F'\t' -pale '
  substr($_,1+index($_,"\t$F[1]"),length($F[1])) =~ tr/ //d;
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

command

```
awk 'NR>1{$2=$2$3;$3=" "}1' filename
```

output

```
Roll NO Name         RandomColumn1    RandomColumn2 
1       JasonJames   my value          my val 3
```